# PTSV и подсветка ошибок

Tags: python, visual-studio

Приветствую всех. Установил значит PTSV на Visual Studio, думал по-человечески говнокодить на питоне, но вот есть одна проблема - нет подсветки ошибок. По сути без нее IDE становится бесполезной.

Пример:

Class1.py

```
class A(object):
def One(self):
    print "Class A"

class B(object):
def Two(self):
    print "Class B"
```

Class2.py

```
import Class1
smp = A();
smp.ABRAKADABRA() //Тут VS говорит, что мол ничего страшного нет и не подсвечивает.
```

Уже практически все настройки облазил и ничего близко не нашел. Может знает кто, как светить ошибки или может этого вообще нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python это не является синтаксической ошибкой. Так как вы вполне себе можете добавить метод к классу или его экземпляру в рантайме.

Comment: Это понятно. Но вполне логично будет подсветить это, так как ни в одном классе этого метода нет. Может быть я просто случайно нажал на клаву и приписал лишний символ к названию метода. Это можно было бы сразу узреть и устранить неприятную ситуацию.

Comment: А какого рода эта ошибка тогда? Вкушайте прелести динамической типизации as is :)

Comment: Кошмар) Никогда бы не сел за питон, обстоятельства заставили)

Comment: @Flasher-11 попробуйте Intellij PyCharm. Там такие вещи как Warning помечаются хотя бы.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)